# How can I remove last digit from decimal number in PHP

Tags: php

I want to remove last digit from decimal number in PHP. 
Lets say I have 14.153. I want it to be 14.15. I will do this step till my number is no longer decimal.

Comment: Do you need to do this one digit at a time, or would it also work if you did it all at once?

Comment: Try using `number_format()` or `round()`?  Or am I not understanding this?

Comment: I need it once in a time for my algorithm.

Comment: `number_format()` returns a string. `round()` would be the better choice if you'll be doing further mathematical calculations.

Comment: What is your final expected output for above example ?

Comment: If you are not doing further calculations you can even use substring.     <?php echo substr('14.153', 0, -1);?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
<?php
$num = 14.153;
$strnum = (string)$num;

$parts = explode('.', $num);
// $parts[0] = 14;
// $parts[1] = 153;

$decimalPoints = strlen($parts[1]);
// $decimalPoints = 3

if($decimalPoints > 0)
{
    for($i=0 ; $i<=$decimalPoints ; $i++)
    {
        // substring($strnum, 0, 0); causes an empty result so we want to avoid it
        if($i > 0)
        {
            echo substr($strnum, 0, '-'.$i).'<br>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo $strnum.'<br>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Edited to account for original float with all decimal points.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo round(14.153, 2);  // 14.15
```

The round second parameter sets the number of digits.

Comment: Since the OP is going to have to do this multiple times, it might be helpful to show a method that adapts to the number of decimal places, rather than hardcoding 2

Comment: I'm afraid that this rounded the number to the second decimal digit.

Comment: This is rounding not "removing" the last decimal as OP requires.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

**[Live DEMO](http://codepad.org/0h7nvRt0)**

```
<?php

  $number = 14.153;

  echo number_format($number,2);
```

Comment: Since the OP is going to have to do this multiple times, it might be helpful to show a method that adapts to the number of decimal places, rather than hardcoding 2

Comment: I'm afraid that this rounded the number to the second decimal digit.